# Manifest a click into another tab instead of the current (default) one in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Let's say there is an element with xpath "//a[@href]" that doesn't have a direct link to it and when clicked opens the **UNKNOWN** url in the current tab. Is there a way to make it open the URL in another tab instead of current one, so basically to "divert" the click into an another tab.

Here is some clarification:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element) # clicks on an element
driver.execute_script("window.open()")
```

First line will click an element, and second would open a new tab, but as it is  these lines aren't connected. Is there a way to execute just one script that would perform the click AND redirect it to be opened in a new tab?

Comment: So you want to open the URL in that link in another tab? I'm a little confused by your question title.

Comment: I also think you have a syntax error in the code you posed: `arguments[0].click();` --- you are missing the parenthesis for calling the "click" method. It won't fix your problem though.

Comment: Yes, () was missing. The thing is, some sites don't have an URL directly written and you can't use driver.get, so the only way to open some URL is by clicking. That click opens in same tab, what I want is to make the click open it in another  tab instead.

Comment: Is the element you want to click on an actual `<a href="...">` tag? Can you post the HTML of the element you want to click on?

Comment: No, it is an <a> element, but no href tag. Correct element path doesn't really matter here. I would give you a link to the site, but it isn't public.

Comment: Can you please post the HTML of the `<a>` tag? JavaScript is doing something behind the scenes, and until we can figure this out we won't be able to answer your question.

Comment: This is a screenshot https://ibb.co/8dXbtn2 I don't see anything special about the tag. What I know is, the click opens in current tab, but I would like to create a new tab and make the click be opened in that one. If this is possible, I imagine it would be one driver.execute_script which would somehow connect those 2 lines I wrote.

Comment: Please post this in your question as code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need that exactly but you could execute JS within a page that would add (or change) `target` attribute of your `a` tag to be `target='_blank'`.

Since you have added one, the link will open the target resource in a new tab (for Chrome).